# ORA-01830 Failure at to_date function if the field contains more than 5 Digits

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a larger SQL Statement, which works just fine, until a field which displays the median duration contains more than 5 Digits in the used field for displaying (B.AGGAVG)

```
to_char(to_date(ROUND(B.AGGAVG), 'SSSSS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') Mittlere_Dauer,
```

This line is causing the ORA Failure, because without its working fine.

It is also working fine as long as B.AGGAVG contains at most 5 Digits.

Comment: If it has more than five digits (or is higher than 86400) then it represents more than 24 hours anyway, so what would you want to see? At best HH24:MI:SS would give you the number of hours mod 24 (if it got that far).

Comment: Yes you are right. The median error Duration shall be displayed. But I cannot Add whole days, or can I? Like DD:HH etc.? It does not work at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `SSSSS` format model represents](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#d56855e1872) the number of seconds past midnight on a day, so it can't accept values of 86400 or above. You will get "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" for values with more than five digits, but you will also get "ORA-01853: seconds in day must be between 0 and 86399" for values between 86400 and 99999.

How you handle this depends on what you want the result to be. You could convert the number of seconds to an interval data type; taking an arbitrary value of 250,000 seconds:

```
select numtodsinterval(250000, 'SECOND') as result
from dual;

RESULT             
-------------------
+02 21:26:40.000000
```

but you can't directly format those. Or you could manually deconstruct the number into time components (based on the number of seconds in a day), and concatenate them into a string:

```
select trunc(250000/86400)
  ||' '|| trunc(mod(250000, 86400)/3600)
  ||':'|| trunc(mod(250000, 3600)/60)
  ||':'|| mod(250000, 60) result
from dual;

RESULT    
----------
2 21:26:40
```

If you don't want a separate number of days then you could usual the manual approach to get the total number of hours (which can be more than 24) instead:

```
select trunc(250000/3600)
  ||':'|| trunc(mod(250000, 3600)/60)
  ||':'|| mod(250000, 60) result
from dual;

RESULT  
--------
69:26:40
```

---

You could also add the seconds to a nominal date of the first day of any year, but this will only work if the values are always above a day:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (250000/86400) - 1, 'FMDDD FMHH24:MI:SS') as result
from dual;

RESULT    
----------
2 21:26:40
```

The problem is the -1 to deal with the Julian date starting from 1 not zero. With a shorter value that goes a bit wrong:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (1000/86400) - 1, 'FMDDD FMHH24:MI:SS') as result
from dual;

RESULT      
------------
365 00:16:40
```

which you could deal with with additional logic, e.g. modifying the format model based on the original value so it only shows the number of days for larger values and shows a fixed zero (or nothing) for smaller values:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (1000/86400) - 1,
  case when 1000 >= 86400 then 'FMDDD FMHH24:MI:SS' else '"0" HH24:MI:SS' end) as result
from dual;

RESULT                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 00:16:40
```

or if you don't want the zero:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (1000/86400) - 1,
  case when 1000 >= 86400 then 'FMDDD FMHH24:MI:SS' else 'HH24:MI:SS' end) as result
from dual;

RESULT                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:16:40
```

... but it's probably not worth the effort.

---

Whichever approach you use, who/whatever consumes this needs to be able to handle and understand whatever value is presented.

---

Demo of various source values from a CTE, showing the output from all the above methods:

```
with b (aggavg) as (
  select 0 from dual
  union all select 0.123 from dual
  union all select 10 from dual
  union all select 100 from dual
  union all select 1000 from dual
  union all select 10000 from dual
  union all select 86399 from dual
  union all select 86400 from dual
  union all select 100000 from dual
  union all select 250000 from dual
  union all select 1000000 from dual
)
select b.aggavg,
  numtodsinterval(round(b.aggavg), 'SECOND') as result1,
  trunc(round(b.aggavg)/86400)
    ||' '|| trunc(mod(round(b.aggavg), 86400)/3600)
    ||':'|| trunc(mod(round(b.aggavg), 3600)/60)
    ||':'|| mod(round(b.aggavg), 60) result2,
  trunc(round(b.aggavg)/3600)
    ||':'|| trunc(mod(round(b.aggavg), 3600)/60)
    ||':'|| mod(round(b.aggavg), 60) result3,
  to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (round(b.aggavg)/86400) - 1,
    case when round(b.aggavg) >= 86400 then 'FMDDD FMHH24:MI:SS'
                                       else '"0" HH24:MI:SS' end) as result4,
  to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (round(b.aggavg)/86400) - 1,
    case when round(b.aggavg) >= 86400 then 'FMDDD FMHH24:MI:SS'
                                       else 'HH24:MI:SS' end) as result5
from b;

    AGGAVG RESULT1             RESULT2     RESULT3     RESULT4     RESULT5    
---------- ------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
         0 +00 00:00:00.000000 0 0:0:0     0:0:0       0 00:00:00  00:00:00   
      .123 +00 00:00:00.000000 0 0:0:0     0:0:0       0 00:00:00  00:00:00   
        10 +00 00:00:10.000000 0 0:0:10    0:0:10      0 00:00:10  00:00:10   
       100 +00 00:01:40.000000 0 0:1:40    0:1:40      0 00:01:40  00:01:40   
      1000 +00 00:16:40.000000 0 0:16:40   0:16:40     0 00:16:40  00:16:40   
     10000 +00 02:46:40.000000 0 2:46:40   2:46:40     0 02:46:40  02:46:40   
     86399 +00 23:59:59.000000 0 23:59:59  23:59:59    0 23:59:59  23:59:59   
     86400 +01 00:00:00.000000 1 0:0:0     24:0:0      1 00:00:00  1 00:00:00 
    100000 +01 03:46:40.000000 1 3:46:40   27:46:40    1 03:46:40  1 03:46:40 
    250000 +02 21:26:40.000000 2 21:26:40  69:26:40    2 21:26:40  2 21:26:40 
   1000000 +11 13:46:40.000000 11 13:46:40 277:46:40   11 13:46:40 11 13:46:40
```

Comment: I only have to display the amount in Hours:Minutes:Seconds and maybe days in front if its too large..

Comment: With the DDD approach you can have it not show the zero for values less than a day; I've added an example. It really depends what you do want to see, and what whoever uses this expects in that situation.

Comment: Hi Alex, first of all thank you very much for your effort. I tried to use the method with the Zero, bit when I change (1000/86400) with my field I get only zeros as result. I also found out, that sometimes the field contains '0' as value.

Comment: I think I got it somehow, I forgot the 86400 as an add. but there is some failure as the first view are correct, but sometimes there is missing about an hour and there are values with 0,xxxx this cannot be calculated as well and delivering zero

Comment: @Fabian - I'm not quite sure what you mean. The `/86400` is part of the calculation, so you replace the `1000` part with yout actual value. And in your original you had a `round()` call so `0.xxx` should be treated a zero. I've added a summary of the methods showing how your `round(b.aggavg)` fits in to them all. Hope that helps. If you have a specific value that you think gives the wrong result then plug that into the CTE and compare, and if it still doesn't look right then tell what that number is.

Comment: I forgot to edit the second '1000'... I used the one without the zeros.. Works brilliantly!! Thank you very very much!